# Thermal Printer in JS (Is there any methode where I can do all testing and development stuff without the need to have a physical thermal printer

Tags: javascript, printing, electron, invoice, thermal-printer

I am creating an electron application and which also have a requirement of  printing invoice via thermal printer but due to certain reasons I cannot get thermal printer(physical). so is there any method using which i can do all printing invoice stuff testing and everything without a real need to have thermal printer thyself.

I will be glad to have a solution regarding this issue.

Comment: There are articles like this [Virtual ESC POS printer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55398308/9014308) and commercial products.[Virtual Printer Driver SDK for Windows – Royalty Free](https://www.colorpilot.com/emfprinterpilot.html)

Comment: thanks for helpin out , i will surely check it out